# How to split the string in java?

Tags: java

```
String str = "AlwinX-road-9:00pm-kanchana travels-25365445421";
String[] names = str.split("-");
```

I want output like following:

> AlwinX-road
>   9:00pm
>   kanchana travels
>   25365445421

Comment: What isn't working about your code?

Comment: How do you want to tell the difference between the first and second `-`?

Comment: You have to give more information. I guess your problem is not just being able to split on '-'. But what exactly is your requirement? I.e. how many dashes are allowed in the first part, and in the others? My advice would be to either use a character as delimiter that is not valid for the different fields, or if you can define the format yourself, use quasi-standard CSV notation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).

Answer (score 2):

```
   Use pattern matching to match your requirement
    String str = "AlwinX-road-9:00pm-kanchana travels-25365445421"; 
    String regex = "(^[A-Z-a-z ]+)[-]+(\\d+:\\d+pm)[-]([a-z]+\\s+[a-z]+)[-](\\d+)";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile( regex ).matcher( str);
    while (matcher.find( ))
    {
    String roadname = matcher.group(1);
    String time = matcher.group(2);
    String travels = matcher.group(3);
    String digits= matcher.group(4);
    System.out.println("time="+time);
    System.out.println("travels="+travels);
    System.out.println("digits="+digits);                           
    }
```

Comment: roadname=AlwinX-road
time=9:00pm
travels=kanchana travels
digits=25365445421. This code gives you the exact output as you wanted

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to include the delimiter in your first output line, you can do the split, and merge the first two element with a `-`: -

```
String[] names = str.split("-");

System.out.println(names[0] + "-" + names[1])
for (int i = 2;i < names.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(names[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `split()` method can't distinguish the dash in `AlwinX-road` and the other dashes in the string, it treats all the dashes the same. You will need to do some sort of post processing on the resulting array. If you will always need the first two strings in the array joined you can just do that. If your strings are more complex you will need to add additional logic to join the strings in the array.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it, assuming the first '-' is always part of a two part identifier.

```
String str = "AlwinX-road-9:00pm-kanchana travels-25365445421";
String[] tokens = str.split("-");
String[] output = new String[tokens.length - 1];
output[0] = tokens[0] + '-' + tokens[1];
System.out.println(output[0]);
for(int i = 1; i < output.length; i++){ 
  output[i] = tokens[i+1];
  System.out.println(output[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to split (with removal of all dashes but the first one).

```
String str = "AlwinX-road-9:00pm-kanchana travels-25365445421";
String[] names = str.split("-");

for (String value : names)
{
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

So its produces:

```
AlwinX
road
9:00pm
kanchana travels
25365445421
```

Notice that "AlwinX" and "road" we split as well since they had a dash in between. So you will need custom logic to handle this case. here is an example how to do it (I used [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)):

```
StringTokenizer tk = new StringTokenizer(str, "-", true);
String firstString = null;
String secondString = null;
while (tk.hasMoreTokens())
{
    final String token = tk.nextToken();
    if (firstString == null)
    {
        firstString = token;
        continue;
    }
    if (secondString == null && firstString != null && !token.equals("-"))
    {
        secondString = token;
        System.out.println(firstString + "-" + secondString);
        continue;
    }
    if (!token.equals("-"))
    {
        System.out.println(token);
    }
}
```

This will produce:

```
AlwinX-road
9:00pm
kanchana travels
25365445421
```

Answer (score 0):

from your format, I think you want to split the first one just before the time part. You can do it this way:

```
String str =yourString;
String beforetime=str.split("-\\d+:\\d+[ap]m")[0]; //this is your first token, 
                                                    //AlwinX-road in your example
String rest=str.substring(beforetime.length()+1);
String[] restNames=rest.split("-");
```

If you really need it all together in one array then see the code below:

```
String[] allTogether=new String[restNames.length+1];//the string with all your tokens
allTogether[0]=beforetime;
System.arraycopy(restNames, 0, allTogether, 1, restNames.length);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use "_" as a separator instead of "-": AlwinX-road_9:00pm_kanchana travels_25365445421

New code:

```
String str = new String("AlwinX-road_9:00pm_kanchana travels_25365445421");
String separator = new String("_");
String[] names = str.split(separator);
for(int i=0; i<names.length; i++){
    System.out.println(names[i]);
}
```